# private IP instead public on Laravel 5 and Centos

Tags: laravel, centos, vhosts

I have a page made with Laravel 5.4 running on a local server which private IP is 192.168.1.131

All the links are made with the host of virtualhost that I've configured on vhost of Centos 6. vhost is like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myapp.myhost.cl
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/app_folder/public"

        <Directory "/var/www/html/app_folder/public">
                AllowOverride All
                Allow from All
        </Directory>
        ScriptAlias /fcgi-bin/ "/var/www/fcgi-bin/"
        <Directory "/var/www/fcgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options None
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_myapp.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_myapp.log combined
</Virtualhost>
```

And in my `.env` file I have:

```
APP_URL=http://myapp.myhost.cl
```

So, if I join to myapp.myhost.cl and I see the source code I can see the links like:

```
<a href="http://myapp.myhost.cl/admin/some-route">
```

All works fine. BUT if I enter to my page from outside of my network, I got the links like:

```
<a href="http://192.168.1.131/app_folder/public/admin/some-route">
```

Plus, I got a redirection on the URL to

http://myapp.myhost.cl/app_folder/app_folder/app_folder/app_folder/app_folder/etc... a lot of app_folder/app_folder/app_folder/>

What can be? Where should I look?
It's a problem of vhost configuration or could be something with Laravel and url assets, base_dir etc?

Comment: It sounds like those external users are accessing your site by ip address, without a host, and the `ServerName myapp.myhost.cl` means your vhost configuration will not match. Perhaps you have a default fallback vhost that points to /var/www?

Comment: Where could I check that? not sure how to see the configs about vhost and stuff

Comment: There are more vhost configurations in either your existing file, in files in that directory, or somewhere close-by. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html